# jquery not changing src of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select element in my HTML, i then have an iframe that displays PDFs. i have some jquery code that should change the "src" attribute of the iframe when a user selects an option but so far i cant seem to get it to trigger. when i click an option from the select nothing happens. i have tried using .change() and .on("change") but they do not work. i have console.log within the function but it does not log anything into the console.

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $("#demo-category").val();
    $("#demo-category").on("change", "#demo-category", function(){
        $("#readframe").attr("src", x);
        console.log(x);
        console.log("test");
   });
});
```

should you need any more information i will provide it if i can.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You're trying to handle a change event on an element with id `demo-category` **that is contained in another element with id** `demo-category`. That's not a valid DOM setup. Also, you're only reading the value once, outside the event handler, so it will never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation (that is, your

```
.on("change", "#demo-category", function(){
```

) is for when the element that triggers the event is *different* from the element that the listener is added to. When you want to add a plain listener to a single element, don't pass another selector - if you do that, the listener won't fire. Instead just call `.on('change', fn...`.

Also, you're retrieving `x` on document load. Retrieve the new value *after* `#demo-category` changes instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#demo-category").on("change", function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#readframe").attr("src", x);
    console.log(x);
    console.log("test");
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` better than looking through the DOM tree once again.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You might also want to add another common event "keyup" in case the user selects the option using a keyboard. In this case, "change" trigger doesn't work always.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#demo-category").on("change", function(){
      $("#readframe").attr("src", $(this).val());
  });
});
```